# Invert order of HTML elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following configuration:

```
<div><div id='box1'>&nbsp;</div><div id='box2'>&nbsp;</div><div id='box3'>&nbsp;</div><div id='box4'>&nbsp;</div></div>
```

what i need to do is to invert the order of the divs

```
<div><div id='box4'>&nbsp;</div><div id='box3'>&nbsp;</div><div id='box2'>&nbsp;</div><div id='box1'>&nbsp;</div></div>
```

is there a fast way to do this with jQuery without cloning, removing and replacing the items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [jQuery Reverse Order](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/reverseorder) plugin.

Comment: thats a cool plugin. But i use this in my own plugin, i don't want to depend on a other one.

Comment: i gonna use his code its pretty simple but effectife:
function() {
 return this.each(function() {
  $(this).prependTo( $(this).parent() );
 });
};

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$top = $('div#thatTopDiv');
$top.children('div').slice(1).each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($top.children().eq(0));
});
```

Edit: [Tested](http://jsbin.com/izave3/edit) and this works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery TinySort plugin to order the items by class name (descending)...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort