# HTML: Reverse Order of 4 nested tags

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, nested

First of all, I think I found an interesting/similar use case, in order to  invert the order of some elements, [here on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684048/invert-order-of-html-elements)

Anyway, I need to change the order of JUST 4 nested tags `<g>`, grand-children of the first tag g having:

```
<g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7" transform="translate(565,0)">
```

This is the original code:

```
<!-- CHANGE this tag g with trasnform="translate(565,0)"  -->
<g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7" transform="translate(565,0)">
  <g zIndex="1">
    <g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(10,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(20,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(30,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(40,3)"></g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
<!-- DON'T CHANGE this tag g with trasnform="translate(580,0)"  -->
<g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7" transform="translate(580,0)">
  <g zIndex="1">
    <g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(1,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(2,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(3,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(4,3)"></g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

And this is what should become:

```
<!-- CHANGE this tag g with trasnform="translate(565,0)"  -->
<g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7" transform="translate(565,0)">
  <g zIndex="1">
    <g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(40,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(30,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(20,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(10,3)"></g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
<!-- DON'T CHANGE this tag g with trasnform="translate(580,0)"  -->
<g class="highcharts-legend" zIndex="7" transform="translate(580,0)">
  <g zIndex="1">
    <g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(1,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(2,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(3,3)"></g>
       <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(4,3)"></g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

Since I have many elements similar to this one but this is the first one, to identify the parent node I want to modify, I came up with:

```
$('.highcharts-legend')[0]
```

Then, I can't go on because I don't get how to select those 3 nested tag g with class "highcharts-legend-item" in order to apply something like this (found in the other post):

```
$top = $('div#thatTopDiv');
$top.children('div').slice(1).each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($top.children().eq(0));
});
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated (since jQuery is not my best skill recently)

**EDIT**:

**1)** I updated the original HTML source in order to have 2 similar parent tags; the first is the one to be modified, the other doesn't nee any changes)

**2)** The nested tags g have become 4 (not 3) just clarify how the order should reverse: (10,20,30,40) --> (40,30,20,10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your html is incorrect. 'g' tag must have closing tag.

```
<g class="highcharts-legend" zindex="7" transform="translate(565,0)">
    <g zindex="1">
        <g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zindex="1" transform="translate(8,3)"></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zindex="1" transform="translate(82,3)"></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item" zindex="1" transform="translate(159,3)"></g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

jQuery code to invert elements

```
var $parent = $('.highcharts-legend>g>g');
var $children = $parent.children();
$parent.append($children.get().reverse());
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you please take a look at the edited question? there's a more complex HTML source to deal with... thanks in advance

Comment: It is not a problem to change $parent selector. As far as I understand, you need invert only first .highcharts-legend. `$parent = $('.highcharts-legend:eq(0)>g>g')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```
//you can write below code inside function and call it when require.

var element = $('.highcharts-legend').find(".highcharts-legend-item:last") 
$(element).insertBefore($('.highcharts-legend').find(".highcharts-legend-item:first"))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you please take a look at the edited question? there's a more complex HTML source to deal with... thanks in advance

Comment: You can write it for only first element like this get your first element with this `var element = $('.highcharts-legend:first').find(".highcharts-legend-item:last")` and `$(element).insertBefore($('.highcharts-legend').find(".highcharts-legend-item:first"))`